# find my styled-component in react dev tool

Tags: reactjs, optimization, components, styled-components, profiler

just like picture show:
[image: in react dev tool => component]

[image: in react dev tool => profiler]

no matter in react-component and react-profiler
I almost cannot point out which component is it

How Should I Do ?